# Text smear effect in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js

I'm pretty experienced with Javascript but haven't delved much into its advanced graphics capabilities (canvas, webGL, three.js, etc). I want to create a distortion effect kind of like [this one](http://supertheagency.com/), except I'd like to apply it to text instead of an image. Basically I want to have some text that looks like plain HTML at first glance but when the user mouses over it, the text should bend/warp/smear in response.

So far I've found two SO posts that are similar but not exactly what I want: the [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17396632/creating-a-text-smear-effect-while-scrolling) is too simple, as I want to warp and bend the text, not just shift it down the page. The [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27715947/three-js-3d-text-bending) is more interesting, as I have a hunch I'll need to use a library like Three.js to achieve this effect, but I want something 2d, not 3d, and I want to actually warp the "shape" of the text, not just spin it around an axis.

I'm wondering how to create this effect, whether there is a name for the specific effect I want (have had trouble finding good examples online), any good examples, advice, anything really. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In three.js you could create your text in shallow 3d, limiting the depth of the letters on the z-axis, so they only appear to be 2d. Then, of course, do not allow any changes to zoom, pan, etc.

Comment: Was interested also, but my videocard doesn't have webGL support. How many my customers whould see that 'ooooppps' in their browsers I thought...couple years later. May be.

Comment: [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544735/how-to-make-rooftext-effect-and-valley-text-effect-in-html5-or-fabric-js/19553200#19553200) a nice 2D way of reforming text created by K3N.

Comment: @JonathanM thanks for the tip, could you point me to relevant docs and/or an example?

Comment: The first demo you showed is just a 2D mesh with maybe a few hundred vertex. Each vertex has both a x,y position (screen space) and a texture coordinate ( image space). If you move the texture coordinate in a circle, each one a little out of phase dependent on its screen space pos you get that FX. You will only get a full screen example like that via webGL. It can be done in canvas but few machines will do it at full frame rate. That example this is basic Just find a example of a 2D textured mesh for webGl and play with the tx,ty coords.

Comment: @Blindman67 thanks for the detail. I will experiment with this tonight and post a gist/fiddle if I find something that achieves what I want. Thanks all for the suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many possibilities.

Here is an example of a simple WEBGL 2D texture drawn onto a standard 2D canvas. There is a bit of boilerplate for mouse,canvas,webGL so you will have to pick it apart yourself.

The FX is in the Fragment Shader. Rather than move the texture coords I just mapped a 2D vector field over the image (pretty much randomly made it up as i went) The vectors offset the pixel lookup from the texture. The `amount` controlled by mouse up and down controls the amount of the FX and the mouse from left to right moves the `Phase` setting.

Moving mouse to the top of the image reduces the effect amount. Bottom right is at max.

.

The function at the bottom `webGLRender` sets the fragment shader values and renders the webGl then 2D context `drawImage` to render to display canvas. The Fragment shader is above that.

As the webGL image is rendered via ctx.draw2D it is easy to resize making the webGL render total display resolution independent. If you have performance issues (image in the mega pixel * 4 + range) you can reduce the input image size

WebGL can not render images that are not from the same domain (tained) unlike 2D canvas webGL requires access to the pixel data to draw textures and thus tained images will make it throw security errors. I have used a 2d canvas rather than an image as I could not find an image the would not taint the canvas.

```js
// boiler plate
const U = undefined;const RESIZE_DEBOUNCE_TIME = 100;
var w,h,cw,ch,canvas,ctx,mouse,createCanvas,resizeCanvas,setGlobals,globalTime=0,resizeCount = 0; 
var L = typeof log === "function" ? log : function(d){ console.log(d); }
createCanvas = function () { var c,cs; cs = (c = document.createElement("canvas")).style; cs.position = "absolute"; cs.top = cs.left = "0px"; cs.zIndex = 1000; document.body.appendChild(c); return c;}
resizeCanvas = function () {
    if (canvas === U) { canvas = createCanvas(); } canvas.width = window.innerWidth; canvas.height = window.innerHeight; ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
    if (typeof setGlobals === "function") { setGlobals(); } if (typeof onResize === "function"){ resizeCount += 1; setTimeout(debounceResize,RESIZE_DEBOUNCE_TIME);}
}
function debounceResize(){ resizeCount -= 1; if(resizeCount <= 0){ onResize();}}
setGlobals = function(){ cw = (w = canvas.width) / 2; ch = (h = canvas.height) / 2; mouse.updateBounds(); }
mouse = (function(){
    function preventDefault(e) { e.preventDefault(); }
    var mouse = {
        x : 0, y : 0, w : 0, alt : false, shift : false, ctrl : false, buttonRaw : 0, over : false, bm : [1, 2, 4, 6, 5, 3], 
        active : false,bounds : null, crashRecover : null, mouseEvents : "mousemove,mousedown,mouseup,mouseout,mouseover,mousewheel,DOMMouseScroll".split(",")
    };
    var m = mouse;
    function mouseMove(e) {
        var t = e.type;
        m.x = e.clientX - m.bounds.left; m.y = e.clientY - m.bounds.top;
        m.alt = e.altKey; m.shift = e.shiftKey; m.ctrl = e.ctrlKey;
        if (t === "mousedown") { m.buttonRaw |= m.bm[e.which-1]; }  
        else if (t === "mouseup") { m.buttonRaw &= m.bm[e.which + 2]; }
        else if (t === "mouseout") { m.buttonRaw = 0; m.over = false; }
        else if (t === "mouseover") { m.over = true; }
        else if (t === "mousewheel") { m.w = e.wheelDelta; }
        else if (t === "DOMMouseScroll") { m.w = -e.detail; }
        if (m.callbacks) { m.callbacks.forEach(c => c(e)); }
        if((m.buttonRaw & 2) && m.crashRecover !== null){ if(typeof m.crashRecover === "function"){ setTimeout(m.crashRecover,0);}}        
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    m.updateBounds = function(){
        if(m.active){
            m.bounds = m.element.getBoundingClientRect();
        }
    }
    m.addCallback = function (callback) {
        if (typeof callback === "function") {
            if (m.callbacks === U) { m.callbacks = [callback]; }
            else { m.callbacks.push(callback); }
        } else { throw new TypeError("mouse.addCallback argument must be a function"); }
    }
    m.start = function (element, blockContextMenu) {
        if (m.element !== U) { m.removeMouse(); }        
        m.element = element === U ? document : element;
        m.blockContextMenu = blockContextMenu === U ? false : blockContextMenu;
        m.mouseEvents.forEach( n => { m.element.addEventListener(n, mouseMove); } );
        if (m.blockContextMenu === true) { m.element.addEventListener("contextmenu", preventDefault, false); }
        m.active = true;
        m.updateBounds();
    }
    m.remove = function () {
        if (m.element !== U) {
            m.mouseEvents.forEach(n => { m.element.removeEventListener(n, mouseMove); } );
            if (m.contextMenuBlocked === true) { m.element.removeEventListener("contextmenu", preventDefault);}
            m.element = m.callbacks = m.contextMenuBlocked = U;
            m.active = false;
        }
    }
    return mouse;
})();

resizeCanvas(); 
mouse.start(canvas,true); 
window.addEventListener("resize",resizeCanvas); 
function display(){ 
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // reset transform
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;           // reset alpha
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
    if(webGL !== undefined){
        webGLRender();
    }
}
function update(timer){ // Main update loop
    globalTime = timer;
    display();  // call demo code
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
requestAnimationFrame(update);
var globalTime = new Date().valueOf();  // global to this 

// creates vertex and fragment shaders 
function createProgramFromScripts( gl, ids) {
    var shaders = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i += 1) {
        var script = shadersSource[ids[i]];
        if (script !== undefined) {
            var shader = gl.createShader(gl[script.type]);
            gl.shaderSource(shader, script.source);
            gl.compileShader(shader);
            shaders.push(shader);  
        }else{
            throw new ReferenceError("*** Error: unknown script ID : " + ids[i]);
        }
    }
    var program = gl.createProgram();
    shaders.forEach((shader) => {  gl.attachShader(program, shader); });
    gl.linkProgram(program);
    return program;    
}

// setup simple 2D webGL image processor
var webGL;
function startWebGL(image) {
  // Get A WebGL context
  webGL = document.createElement("canvas");
  webGL.width = image.width;
  webGL.height = image.height;
  webGL.gl = webGL.getContext("webgl");
  var gl = webGL.gl;
  var program = createProgramFromScripts(gl, ["VertexShader", "FragmentShader"]);
  gl.useProgram(program);
  var positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position");
  var texCoordLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_texCoord");
  var texCoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texCoordBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([0.0,  0.0,1.0,  0.0,0.0,  1.0,0.0,  1.0,1.0,  0.0,1.0,  1.0]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(texCoordLocation);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(texCoordLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  var texture = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
  var resolutionLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_resolution");

  // lookup uniforms for frag shader
  var locs = {}
  locs.timer = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "time");  // the time used to control waves
  locs.phase = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "phase"); // Sort of phase, moves to attractors around
  locs.amount = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "amount"); // Mix amount of effect and flat image
  webGL.locs = locs;
  
  gl.uniform2f(resolutionLocation, webGL.width, webGL.height);
  var buffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  setRectangle(gl, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
}
function setRectangle(gl, x, y, width, height) {
  var x1 = x;
  var x2 = x + width;
  var y1 = y;
  var y2 = y + height;
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
     x1, y1,
     x2, y1,
     x1, y2,
     x1, y2,
     x2, y1,
     x2, y2]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}

function randomInt(range) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * range);
}



var shadersSource = {
    VertexShader : {
        type : "VERTEX_SHADER",
        source : `
            attribute vec2 a_position;
            attribute vec2 a_texCoord;
            uniform vec2 u_resolution;
            varying vec2 v_texCoord;
            void main() {
                vec2 zeroToOne = a_position / u_resolution;
                vec2 zeroToTwo = zeroToOne * 2.0;
                vec2 clipSpace = zeroToTwo - 1.0;
                gl_Position = vec4(clipSpace * vec2(1, -1), 0, 1);
                v_texCoord = a_texCoord;
            }`
    },
    FragmentShader : {
        type : "FRAGMENT_SHADER",
        source : `
            precision mediump float;
            uniform sampler2D u_image;
            uniform float time;
            uniform float phase;
            uniform float amount;
            varying vec2 v_texCoord;
            vec2 offset;
            float dist;
            float edge;
            float v;
            vec2 pos1 = vec2(0.5 + sin(phase * 0.03)*1.3, 0.5 + cos(phase * 0.032)*1.3);
            vec2 pos2 = vec2(0.5 + cos(phase * 0.013)*1.3,0.5 + cos(phase*0.012)*1.3);
            void main() {
                dist = distance(pos1,v_texCoord) * distance(pos2,v_texCoord);

               
                edge = 1. - distance(vec2(0.5,0.5),v_texCoord) / 0.707;
                v = time * dist * 0.0001 * edge * phase;
                offset = vec2(
                        v_texCoord.x + sin(v+time) * 0.1 * edge * amount,
                        v_texCoord.y + cos(v+time) * 0.1 * edge * amount
                );
                //offset = smoothstep(v_texCoord.x,offset.x,abs(0.5-v_textCoord.x) );
                gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_image, offset);
            }`
    }
}


var md = 0;
var mr = 0;
var mdy = 0;
var mry = 0;
function webGLRender(){
    var gl = webGL.gl;
    md += (mouse.x / canvas.width - mr) * 0.16;
    md *= 0.18;
    mr += md;  
    mdy += (mouse.y - mry) * 0.16;
    mdy *= 0.18;
    mry += mdy;
    gl.uniform1f(webGL.locs.timer, globalTime/100);
    gl.uniform1f(webGL.locs.phase, mr * 400);
    gl.uniform1f(webGL.locs.amount, ((mry/canvas.height)) * 9);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    ctx.drawImage(webGL,0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

var image = document.createElement("canvas");
image.width = 1024;
image.height = 512;
image.ctx = image.getContext("2d");
image.ctx.font = "192px Arial";
image.ctx.textAlign = "center";
image.ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
image.ctx.lineJoin = "round";
image.ctx.lineWidth = 32;
image.ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
image.ctx.fillStyle = "black";
image.ctx.strokeText("WOBBLE",512,256);
image.ctx.lineWidth = 16;
image.ctx.strokeStyle = "white";

image.ctx.strokeText("WOBBLE",512,256);
image.ctx.fillText("WOBBLE",512,256);
image.ctx.font = "32px Arial";
image.ctx.fillText("Mouse position on image controls wobble",512,32);
image.ctx.fillText("Using WebGL and 2D Canvas",512,512-32);

startWebGL(image);
/*var image = new Image(); // load image
image.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7qq2.png?s=328&g=1";  // MUST BE SAME DOMAIN!!!
image.onload = function() {
    startWebGL(image);
}*/
```

Comment: Wow. Can't thank you enough for this thorough example, this is exactly the type of thing I was looking for. thanks so much!