# 2D Rendering On Top Of A WebGL Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, webgl

I am using a library for drawing Normal-Mapped images on a HTML-Canvas. It does so with Web-GL Acceleration. ([NormalMap.js](https://github.com/jwagner/normalmap.js/))

However, I would also like to draw onto the canvas using a 2D Canvas Context (Rects, images, text, etc).

How can this be achieved? The library fails to work if a 2D Context is created, throwing the error `webgl not supported!`(without the second context the library functions perfectly.)

One way to do this might be to overlay another transparent canvas, but is there a better way?

Thank you!

Comment: You can render the webGL canvas onto a 2D canvas via the 2D API. Just get the 2D context for the displayed canvas, and just hold the webGL canvas in memory. This https://stackoverflow.com/a/38966946/3877726 shows a webGL canvas rendered and then drawn on a second canvas via the 2D API.

Comment: You might have got an issue while doing your edit

Comment: https://maximumroulette.com/webgl2 find example for texture porting . You can use canvas 2d for draws and hide it then use image from canvas2d  for texture in webgl .

Comment: @NikolaLukic Yeah, I'm afraid that looks like the best option. To me, it seems a bit hack-y, but hey, this is programming...

Comment: it is ;) Take a look at : https://bitbucket.org/nikola_l/visual-js/overview In this project you can found 3 version of graphic language. Canvas2D , webGL also webGL2 all are standalone part but you can compine them .For 2d part you can found examples also for webgl2. (in canvas2D you can draw custom - any native example look at examples)